# (Psalms 69 (14)) How do we understand אלקים ברב חסדך, rather than ה׳ ברב חסדך

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tehilim-psalms

I am used to the idea that the name אלקים connotes judgement and ה׳ mercy. 
So how is it in [Psalms 69 (14)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51767&st=&pgnum=142) , the Psalmist says “אלקים ברב חסדך”?

Answer (score 6):

Rabbi Shmuel of Lubavitch, the Rebbe Maharash asks this question in a discourse ([Toras Shmuel 5632 Chelek 1 pg. 164](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15933&pgnum=171)) and explains as follows:

There are two types of chesed (kindness): a "worldly" kindness ("chesed olam"), and a kindness that supersedes the natural order of things ("rav chesed"). While the regular, worldly type of kindness contradicts and apposes the idea of gevurah (severity), the super-worldly kindness actually sweetens the severity. Since the verse here mentions this later type of chesed; "berov chasdecha", it does not contradict the name of Elokim which represents severity.